# Why getting TypeScript Eslint "Unnecessary conditional, value is always truthy eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition"

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have these examples (amongst other, switching over to TypeScript from JS).

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Where `let diff = (oldIndent - newIndent) / 2` on the last one.

Why is it doing this? Is it some bug? What am I doing wrong?

### .prettierrc

```
{
  "semi": false,
  "trailingComma": "all",
  "singleQuote": true,
  "printWidth": 64,
  "tabWidth": 2,
  "useTabs": false,
  "arrowParens": "avoid",
  "quoteProps": "as-needed",
  "bracketSpacing": true,
  "proseWrap": "always",
  "endOfLine": "lf",
  "singleAttributePerLine": true,
  "prettierPath": "./node_modules/prettier"
}
```

### tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es2020",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "outDir": "host",
    "rootDir": "make",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true
  },
  "include": ["make"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

### .eslintrc.json

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaVersion": "latest",
    "sourceType": "module",
    "project": ["./tsconfig.json"]
  },
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
  "extends": [],
  "rules": {
    "curly": 2,
    "brace-style": ["error", "1tbs"],
    "@typescript-eslint/quotes": [
      "error",
      "single",
      {
        "avoidEscape": true,
        "allowTemplateLiterals": true
      }
    ],
    "@typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-condition": {
      "allowConstantLoopConditions": true
    }
  }
}
```

### .vscode/settings.json

```
{
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "eslint.format.enable": true,
  "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
    "source.fixAll.eslint": true
  },
  "eslint.validate": ["javascript", "typescript"],
  "eslint.nodePath": "./node_modules/eslint",
  "eslint.packageManager": "npm"
}
```

It's getting weird.... I tried closing and opening the file again, but same issues. (Squigglies here show same issue).

[image]

Notice how it is appearing a bunch in random places (as shown by the sidebar on the right).

[image]

Comment: Restarting VSCode completely might help

Comment: That seemed to have fixed it... Now I changed eslint config again and added a new rule, reformatted the code, and I'm getting new weird errors. Do I have to restart VSCode after every config change?

Comment: Restarting VSCode also worked for me.